# Styled component throws weird typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I have styled components and typescript in my RN Project

Typescript is throwing a weird error in one of my files, it says `Element implicitly has 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index 'ColorKeyType'`

The affected code, the error is at the `return theme.colors[color]` part

```
const StyledText = styled(Text)<TextStyleProps>`
  color: ${({ color, theme }) => {
    if (color) {
      return theme.colors[color] || color;
    }
    return theme.colors.text;
  }}
`;
```

My theme color is typed like:

```
interface ColorKeyType {
  primary: string;
  ... more colors like the one above
}
```

then I use the type like:

```
{
    colors: ColorKeyType;
    fonts: {
      families: {
        primary: { [key in FontFamilyType]: string };
      };
      fontSize: { [key in FontSizeType]: number };
      letterSpacing: number;
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance for any possible solutions!

Answer (score 0):

change your color type to `keyof ColorKeyType`

```js
interface TextStyleProps {
  ...
  color: keyof ColorKeyType;
}
```